# Compress and Delete multiple folders one by one

Tags: windows, powershell

Ho Guys,

I was trying a powershell script which can compress and delete the subfolders with folder name of 8 numbers.
The script is working fine. But the problem is the script works like, first the whole compression process gets done and then goes for the whole deletion. So that if am running this script through 1tb folder...During the compression process it goes upto 1.5tb . To overcome this, how can I change the script so that the script should compress and delete one folder and moves to next folder compress and delete and so on.

Here is what I tried.

```
$path = Read-host "Enter the desired path"
$directory = "$path"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$folders = Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name.Length -ge "8" -and $_.Name -match '^\d+$'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
Write-Verbose "Archiving $archive"
$archive = $folder + '.zip'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($folder, $archive, 'Optimal', $True) | wait-process
}
Foreach-Object {
Remove-Item -Path $folders -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Verbose
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$path = Read-host "Enter the desired path"
$directory = "$path"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$folders = Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name.Length -ge "8" -and $_.Name -match '^\d+$'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
Write-Verbose "Archiving $archive"
$archive = $folder + '.zip'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($folder, $archive, 'Optimal', $True)
Remove-Item $folder -recurse -force
}
```